# How secure (about spyware/backdoor in it) is LibreOffice? Should I start using OpenOffice?

Tags: privacy, backdoor

I'm using LibreOffice now, and I'm encrypting files of LO Write with VeraCrypt that have very personal content and I want to keep it secret. But I read about LO send to his web SO MUCH information, and I read an entry (that I cannot find again right now) that says he save so much secret information using LibreOffice like me, he have Comodo Firewall and he sees that the trusted files list of his Firewall, get double when he installs LO and sees that that files send a few KB of information. And he starts a difficult uninstall of LO all files.

Do you know anything about if write and open files with LibreOffice is 100% secure? Should I change to OpenOffice or any other software?

Comment: LibreOffice is not 100% secure. There _are_ 0days for it out there. OpenOffice is pretty much unmaintained, so I would suggest to just keep using LibreOffice.

Comment: Why is not 100%secure? if we are talking about privacy

Comment: Nothing is 100% secure. It doesn't have any spyware or "backdoors" that will intentionally do bad things to you by default, but it can be "hacked" by malicious documents.

Comment: Unless it is encrypted by LibreOffice, wireshark or tcpdump will record all traffic and you can manually inspect it.  Operating system have many background services so expect really large logs to sift through, and not all the traffic will belong to LibreOffice.  And even if it is encrypted you can see the source and destination IP(s) and do whois lookup to see where the traffic is going.  Obviously if you link, but not embed things in your documents it will have to reach out to the source material in order to display it.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is safe to say that LibreOffice does not contain any backdoors or spyware and does not send your files over the Internet. LibreOffice is as secure as any other word processor such as OpenOffice or Microsoft Word. You could even say it is more secure, since it is open source and it would be pretty hard to hide malicious code in it.

Comment: Saying something is as secure as Microsoft Word doesn't sound like very high praise

Answer (score 2):

You are safer with libreoffice. What you mention about telemetry (i.e. a program collecting information on how it is used and sending to the author's server) doesn't happen with libreoffice, but does happen with Microsoft word and apple's clone.

OpenOffice should not be used! It have not been updated for the last 9 years. see full history at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice#History

LibreOffice have its own questions website like this one. here is a link to the same question there: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/89256/does-libreoffice-snoop-on-users-documents-really/

That said, all large programs today (and an office suite is huge!) have some sort of plugin system. LibreOffice have two such systems (that i know of): macros and extensions.

extension you have to actively install yourself. Just don't i guess.

Macros are more complicated, the can came within a document you open. If I recall correctly, libreOffice will show a security warning when that happens allowing you to accept or not. And it can also be disabled globally on the preferences.